# XA transaction MongoDb and Rabbit MQ

Tags: mongodb, rabbitmq

I have case of xa transaction between mongo db and Rabbit mq. Data should get commited in both and should rollback. Commit in mongo db and post message to rabbit mq. If one fails it should automatically rollover. I am using this in my spring boot app. Do we have xa transaction manager which handles??

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please get familiar with https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, neither RabbitMQ nor MongoDB support XA at this time. Otherwise, you might be able to use atomikos (https://www.atomikos.com).

So either consider using a different broker and DB, or ask them to support XA.